# how to search string in whole string in loopback query

Tags: javascript, regex, loopback

I want search whole string when I type any word,  it's matched only first Character not matched whole string and middle character of string.

```
query.and.push({ or: [{ name: { like: '^' + data.searchTextNEM + '.*', options: 'i' } }, { email: { like: '^' + data.searchTextNEM + '.*', options: 'i' } },{ phone: { like: '^' + data.searchTextNEM + '.*', options: 'i' } }]});

Users.find({where: query, limit: data.limit,skip: data.skip },function(err,res){})
```

Like I have two string `1.mark` and `2.denim`  if I type `'m'` my response should be mark and denim but getting response only `mark`

Comment: Ignore - just looked into what `loopback` is. FYI the loopback stackoverflow tag seems to point to something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have try this:-

```
name: { ilike: '%' + data.searchTextNEM + '%' }
```

It will also match with case insensitive text.

**or:**

you may have pass the options in like filter:-

```
?filter={"where":{"title":{"like":"someth.*","options":"i"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex is incorrect. If you insert 'm' your regex becomes `^m.*` which means "starts with m and then has any number of any characters". I think you want `.*m.*` which means "has any number of any character, then an m, then any number of any character":

```
query.and.push({ or: [{ name: { like: '.*' + data.searchTextNEM + '.*', options: 'i' } }, { email: { like: '.*' + data.searchTextNEM + '.*', options: 'i' } },{ phone: { like: '.*' + data.searchTextNEM + '.*', options: 'i' } }]});
 Users.find({where: query, limit: data.limit,skip: data.skip },function(err,res){
})
```